# Is it possible to use wildcards in Firestore TTL policies?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I assume the answer is no since I haven't seen anything in the documentation but I thought I will check with the experts anyway.

Ideally I would like to specify * for the document kind, and `expireBy` as the timestamp property when I define the policy. Firebase would then delete all documents which

- A. Has an `expireBy` property
- B. its `expireBy` property has passed the current date

Is this possible? If not I guess I must define a new TTL policy each time I add a new entity kind to Firebase, doable of course but I'm still trying to find a way around it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to apply a TTL policies to the entire database - regardless of which collection the documents exist in.

As you already guessed, what you want to do is not currently a feature of Firestore's TTL policies.

You *could* file a request for this feature [with Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) or on [firebase.uservoice.com](https://firebase.uservoice.com), but I'll admit it's unlikely to gain much traction - due to the disruptive nature such a global policy could have in case of mistakes.